# How to bind ObservableCollections to a TreeView and display the corresponding views?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I would like to build a TreeView from two user controls, which are to be built up hierarchically (item beneath header). This should be done by binding two nested `ObservableCollection`. Since all controls are already defined in the subordinate views themselves, they should not be defined in the superordinate view.

As I understand it, it should be enough to set the itemsource of the treeview and then define the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and the "underlying" `DataTemplate`.

Unfortunately, however, the assignment of view and viewmodel is not applied with the following setting:

App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:EvaluationHeaderViewModel}">
    <Views:EvaluationHeaderView/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:EvaluationItemViewModel}">
    <Views:EvaluationItemView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The TreeView:

```
<TreeView 
    MaxHeight="500"
    Name="EvaluationTreeView"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
    Grid.Row="4" 
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EvaluationHeaderViewModels, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
    >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:EvaluationHeaderViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding EvaluationItemViewModels}"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:EvaluationItemViewModel}"/>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The Lists:

```
private ObservableCollection<EvaluationHeaderViewModel> evaluationHeaderViewModels;
public ObservableCollection<EvaluationHeaderViewModel> EvaluationHeaderViewModels {
    get => evaluationHeaderViewModels;
    set
    {
        evaluationHeaderViewModels = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<EvaluationItemViewModel> EvaluationItemViewModels { get; set; }

public EvaluationHeaderViewModel()
{
    EvaluationItemViewModels = new ObservableCollection<EvaluationItemViewModel>();
    EvaluationItemViewModels.Add(new EvaluationItemViewModel());
}
```

How can I bind the ObservableCollections to the TreeView so that the UserControls are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to define the templates twice. Either remove the `<TreeView.Resources>` element or define the actual templates to be used there instead of in `App.xaml`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding EvaluationHeaderViewModels}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:EvaluationHeaderViewModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding EvaluationItemViewModels}">
            <Views:EvaluationHeaderView/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:EvaluationItemViewModel}">
            <Views:EvaluationItemView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Removing the viewmodel and view definition from `App.xaml` and including it directly in the `<TreeView.Resources>` as suggested solved the problem.